# Spring Eclipse STS horrible code completion performance

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm at the mercy of being on a corporate laptop but since using Eclipse STS for spring development for the last few years both the previous and current version I have always had issues with code completion freezing for a few seconds or throwing an exception with missing content message. My question is, how can I get my sanity back being able to code quickly and not have to wait seconds at a time just to get a code completion suggestion in the java editor for spring STS. is this a known bug? this does not happen in other flavors of eclipse and it really makes the product less desirable to use, but i guess that is the reality of open source software I appreciate all the development effort put into this product just hope someone can help me resolve this code completion issue because it really slows me down. - Duncna

Comment: _"is this a known bug?"_ STS3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues - STS4: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues

Comment: The best thing to do is file a bug report and try to help the STS developers trouble-shoot your issue. This is a performance issue and it probably means some component contributing completions is not responding in a timely manner. It would have to determined precisely what/why this happens and then the STS developers might be able to optimise something to improve it. I suggest you file a bug at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and try to include as much detail as possible to help reproduce the problem. Include some stacktraces if you can, taken during the 'freeze'.

Comment: Kudos to Kris and Howlger, i did find a bug that was related to auto completion but not the issue I'm having and Kris, i'll take your advice by getting all the information I can when it happens and reporting that as an issue on git hub. Thanks guys